# Pass index of a List to button click event sender

Tags: c#, wpf, arrays, list

I have a List and each Button calls to the same Click function

```
List<Button> btnList = new List<Button>;

// function to add a new button
Button btn = new Button();
btn.Click += showIndex_Click;
btnList.Add(btn);

private void showIndex_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     MessageBox.Show(???);  
}
```

The click event will display the index of the sender Button. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sender parameter is the Button who fired the event. You can use it to search in the list and find its index.

```
var button = sender as Button;
var index = btnList.IndexOf(button);
```

Comment: I did what you suggest and all buttons give me a "-1" index

Comment: That means that the button is not on the list. Are you defining buttons in XAML?

Answer (score 1):

here clickbtn will store all the informattion about the button that is clicked.

So you can get the index about that button

```
private void showIndex_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     Button clickbtn = sender as Button;

     MessageBox.Show(???);  
}
```